# Install libtorrent under Windows

Tags: torrent, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

How to install [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/) under Windows? Also, would it be possible to make it portable by including all the libraries and files it needs the same folder?

Comment: what do you mean by "install" exactly? On windows, as far as I know, there is no definitive convention of where one installs shared libraries and headers. You could stick them directly in visual studio's include directory, but reinstalling or upgrading visual studio would break it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two routes, compile libtorrent-rasterbar with Visual C++ or install the dynamic library using the installer provided:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libtorrent/files/py-libtorrent/

Using the installer will place the libtorrent dll in your Python site-packages directory and make libtorrent-rasterbar available in your Python interpreter.

Please note the dynamic library provided with the installer is only available for certain Python versions and only 32 bit.